# mvc3 unusual routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two routes except for default:

```
routes.MapRoute("ShopDefault",
                "Shop/{id}/{action}",
                new { controller = "Shop" });
routes.MapRoute("Shop",
                "Shop/{id}/List/{categoryID}",
                new { controller = "Shop", action = "List"});
```

The first route works perfectly, links like `.../Shop/3/Index`, `.../Shop3/Messages` are correctly processed.

But for the second route - links like `.../Shop/3/List/5` are not found. Anyone know why?

Comment: Something's missing here.  First of all, you shouldn't use relative links like that with MVC routing.  Can you post some more context about the pages where you're placing the links, and other routes?

Answer (score 3):

Your more explicit route should be first, the routing engine is attempting to match Shop/Id/Action in ShopDefault and then probably failing and giving you a 404 before it gets to your more explicit route of Shop.

You should put the routes in the opposite order:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Shop",
                "Shop/{id}/List/{categoryID}",
                new { controller = "Shop", action = "List"},
                new { id= @"\d+" }

            routes.MapRoute(
                "ShopDefault",
                "Shop/{id}/{action}",
                new { controller = "Shop" });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help

Comment: I made an update to my answer, adding a routing constraint.  My constraint assume that id is an integer so the routing engine can handle this properly.  You may also want to adjust your route so it's Shop/List/{id}/{categoryID} so to make the matching easier